# How to compare the workspace variable names with a list of strings (cell array)?

Tags: string, list, matlab, function, variables

I have a lot of variables in the base workspace. I have a list of strings containing valid names. So let's say the base workspace contains the variable names `var1`, `var2`, `var3`, `var4`, `var5`, `var6`, `var7`, `var8`, `var9`, `var10` and the list of strings is a cell array equal to :

```
listParam = {'var4' 'var7' 'var10'};
```

Now, I want to check if the strings that are in `listParam` have a corresponding declared variable in the base workspace. Here what I have done so far :

```
function [compareCellArrayList] = test(listParam)
S = evalin('base','whos'); % Looks for the variables in the base workspace
listWorkspaceVariable = cell(size(S)); % Pre-allocate
for ii = 1:length(S)
    listWorkspaceVariable{ii,1} = S(ii,1).name; % Gets the variable name of each variable
end
compareCellArrayList = cellfun(@(x) ismember(x, listParam), listWorkspaceVariable, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

The code above is working correctly, but it's just that i have a feeling it could be simplified while still being easy to understand. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace lines 3 to 6 with

```
listWorkspaceVariable = {S.name};
```

Also you can use `ismember` with two cell arrays so last line can be rewritten

```
compareCellArrayList = ismember(listWorkspaceVariable, listParam);
```

so it will be like

```
function [listWorkspaceVariable] = test(listParam)
S = evalin('base','whos'); % Looks for the variables in the base workspace
listWorkspaceVariable = {S.name};
compareCellArrayList = ismember(listWorkspaceVariable, listParam);
```

By the way, it seems that your function is not returning `compareCellArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

`doesexist = ismember(listParam,{S.name})`